# SQL file executes with no error but also no results through shell script

Tags: sql, bash, oracle, shell, pdb

I have a sqlfile that I want to run via shell script against an Oracle pluggable database. The sql file basically just loops through table names to apply grants to a role. When I run the script, it looks like it executes the file, but it really doesnt, no grants are applied. When I log into sqlplus and execute the sql file manually, it does actually execute and I see the output I expect.

Can someone help me understand the reason for this behavior and how to resolve it?

==SCRIPT==

```
#!/bin/ksh

ORACLE_SID=${1}
TWO_TASK=${2}

sqlplus -s sys/${sys_password}@${TWO_TASK} as sysdba << !EOSQL! >> ${output}
        @/tmp/foobar.sql MY_SCHEMA;
exit
!EOSQL!
```

==SCRIPT RESULT==

```
SQL> SQL> old   7: select substr('&1',6,6) into rolesuffix from dual;
new   7: select substr('MY_SCHEMA',6,6) into rolesuffix from dual;
old   8: FOR lCursorRec in (select * from dba_objects where object_type in ('TABLE', 'VIEW') and owner in ('&1'))
new   8: FOR lCursorRec in (select * from dba_objects where object_type in ('TABLE', 'VIEW') and owner in ('MY_SCHEMA'))

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

==RUN ON COMMAND LINE==

```
SQL> @/tmp/foobar.sql MY_SCHEMA;
old   7: select substr('&1',6,6) into rolesuffix from dual;
new   7: select substr('MY_SCHEMA',6,6) into rolesuffix from dual;
old   8: FOR lCursorRec in (select * from dba_objects where object_type in ('TABLE', 'VIEW') and owner in ('&1'))
new   8: FOR lCursorRec in (select * from dba_objects where object_type in ('TABLE', 'VIEW') and owner in ('MY_SCHEMA'))

GRANT SELECT ON MY_SCHEMA."TABLE_A" TO READ_ROLE
GRANT SELECT ON MY_SCHEMA."TABLE_B" TO READ_ROLE
.
.
.
```

Comment: Do you need to start and commit a transaction? I have not used Oracle, but maybe if you don't commit the transaction the changes are not applied. A wild guess.

Comment: It is just a `grant` so it wouldn't need a `commit`

Comment: @roccobaroccoSC - GRANT is a DDL statement, not DML.  In oracle, all DDL statements are self-committing.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the same database - in the command line version, is your `sqlplus` call exactly the same (apart from the -s)? Without seeing your SQL code, it looks like you're looping over tables with a specific owner - and as it doesn't seem to find any, you might be in the wrong place...

Comment: @exit_1 - it would certainly help if you were to show the actual sql script as well as the shell script.  Can you debug code that you cannot see?

Comment: @EdStevens, I had decided to keep from posting the sql file so as to not make the post too long, and also I was figuring the problem was more in the way of the script that I did post since the sql works when executed via command line. But I can post the sql file too

Comment: @AlexPoole, I'll double check that it is actually going to the database I want. I'll examine audit trail

Comment: @AlexPoole, you were right, I thought I was setting my environment to connect to the pdb correctly but I wasn't. I was connect to CDB so it didn't find any schemas it was expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At advice of commenter, I double checked the script was logging into the PDB correctly, but it wasn't, it was going to the CDB so the sqlfile that runs without error couldn't find expected schemas. Updated script to do away with `TWO_TASK` since I was using it incorrectly and need to read more of the documentation on it, and logged in directly to PDB.

```
orasid=${TWO_TASK}
.
.
.
sqlplus -s sys/${sys_password}@${orasid} as sysdba << !EOSQL! >> ${output}
        @/tmp/foobar.sql MY_SCHEMA;
exit
!EOSQL!
```